# How can I minimize Flutter app programaticaly and without closing the app?

Tags: flutter, mobile, minimize

I  used minimize_app package from
https://pub.dev/documentation/minimize_app/latest/ but it doesnt work.

Error:

```
**Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
```

e:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\minimize_app0.1.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\vanethos\minimize_app\MinimizeAppPlugin.k: (34, 33): Type mismatch: inferred type is DartExecutor? but BinaryMessenger was expected**

I imported the package:

```
import 'package:minimize_app/minimize_app.dart';
```

and added the dependency in pubspec.yaml

```
minimize_app: ^0.1.1
```

Im calling the minimize from a button on the app:

```
onPressed: (){                  
    MinimizeApp.minimizeApp();
},
```

Ive tried  a previous version: minimize_app: 0.1.0 from https://pub.dev/documentation/minimize_app/latest but it doesnt help. It looks like 0.1.1 is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

@Ishmael Mavor Raines I came across this package on `pub.dev` and it proved to be very effective for my use case. Additionally, I found it to be user-friendly and straightforward to implement.

https://pub.dev/packages/move_to_background

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a null safety package and is competitive with Dart 3:

[app_minimizer](https://pub.dev/packages/app_minimizer)